# GIT under VPN works only with hotspot, not home router/wifi

Tags: git, wifi, vpn, nat, hotspot

This one is my first post ever, so I'll try to write it in the clearest way possible!

I remotely work for a company, so I have :

1. **VPN** (Pulse Secure)
2. **SSH** Certificates to reach the remote repos. Certificates are correct.
3. Access to the remote repo - **GIT**
4. Acces to the remote **DBs**.

I have 2 scenarios to sum up my question:

**Scenario 1**

- Laptop connected through my phone hotspot;
- I connect the laptop to the VPN.
- VPN is connected.
- I can reach the DBs through SQL CLient;
- My local server (wildfly 10) deploys my war and services are correctly up and running;
- I can use Git to pull/push/ecc...
- **Everything works.**

**Scenario 2**

- Laptop connected through home-wifi (Router Netgear D6000) and to the VPN.
- Vpn is connected.
- I **can** see the DBs from SQL clients.
- I cannot use GIT.
- **Every push/pull is a fail.**
  Git error from Eclipse: `Failed (UnresolvedAddressException) to execute: null`
- I cannot even deploy correctly the .war on my local server because when the server tries to create the connection pool to communicate with the DBs, it goes in time-out.

For a short amount of time, I managed to work with my laptop over wifi-vpn connection because I saw in router settings that the NAT was not active and I switched it to "Active". 
It worked for like 2 weeks. 
Maybe there were some sort of policy that I didn't respect due to the NAT set as Inactive.
**Then, same problem again**. I checked my router conf and everything is as it was after my adjustment.

Anyone can figure it out? There is away for me to work connected through my wifi and not the freaky hotspot? 
Many thanks.

p.s. Or if there is some way to know if it is a problem ISP-side, VPN-side or .. my system settings side.
 I read a post on Quora where I can say that, probably, is something that depends from some of my settings but is a problem so peculiar that I cannot figure it out what is the specific cause to all of that.

Error from Git Bash while wifi+vpn:

```
$ git pull

ssh: Could not resolve hostname git.companyname.it: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Please show us the error when using the command-line Git client by editing your question to insert it into a code block.  That will provide more useful information than the EGit error you're getting.

Comment: thanks bk2204, I added it... the error makes it look like I would not be under VPN but I am, I can reach their DBs with that same VPN... and the SSH certificates and the repos are correct since under hotspot I have no problem.